# Why does the char array method "ToString" returns a promt System.Char instead of reversed string?

Tags: c#

I don't know why but first Console.WriteLine returns reversed string whereas second returns prompt "System.Char[]" instead of reversed string.

```
        string name;
        string reversedName2;
        Console.Write("Enter your name:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] letters = name.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(letters);
        String reversedName = new string(letters);
        reversedName2 = letters.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(reversedName);
        Console.WriteLine(reversedName2);
```

Comment: If a class does not ahve a override for ToString(), the default beahvior inherited from Object is to return the name of the class.  And indeed the array "letters" is of type "System.Char[]".

Comment: This is asked almost weekly.

Comment: I couldn't find similar topic but thanks for replying anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

.NET arrays won't join the string for you when you call `.ToString()`. By the default implementation, it returns the type name.

You have to convert it either using the `String` constructor (like have you done) or `String.Join`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an array of (something), and arrays don't override the `ToString` method with specialized behaviour that would require knowledge of the contained type.

You could instead:

```
var someString = new String(someCharArray);
```